# WinForms: What is the proper way to change the font style (underline) from a Label at runtime?

Tags: .net, winforms

C#: What is the proper way to change the font style (underline) from a Label at runtime?

So far I understand that if you want to change font related properties at runtime from a label, mainly all font properties, you would have to use,

```
 lblName.Font = new Font(... etc. etc.
```

Is there a shortcut to the above but only assign nothing but a new Font style such FontStyle.Underline?

or

Would I have to proceed with using the "new Font()" method and assign all fields along with it too just to underline my label?

Comment: You might want to specify want windowing you are using (Winforms or WPF).

Answer (score 15):

The way you did it:

```
this.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
```

is correct. The reason is that Font is a sealed and immutable type (by design). When introduced in .NET 1 this seemed a bit strange but with today's emphasis on functional programming, concurrency and immutability this style is seen a lot more. Perhaps it was done this way since controls inherit the font of their container and tracking individual font property changes would be more work than tracking a wholesale font change.

Answer (score 2):

Resorted to,

> this.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Underline);

Works for Win32 Forms.

Comment: That was all I came up with either.  I don't think that is too bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Bold.
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold); 

//Bold With Underline.
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline); 

//Bold with Underline with Italic.
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Italic);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about (I'm using .Net Framework 2.0)  Okay so this works for a Web Application.  In a forms application it is read-only.

lblName.Font.Underline = true;

Here's the definition:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the font is underlined.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the font is underlined; otherwise, false. The default value is false.
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    public bool Underline { get; set; }
```

Comment: Won't function because font.underline is a read-only property.

Comment: Are you sure?  I tried it before I posted it and it worked.  What version are you using?

Comment: Oops never mind.  This works for a Web Ap, not a Windows one.